# Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"VM Exception while processing transaction}. Any solution?

Tags: solidity, remix, blockchain

[image]

why i am getting error? calling the function getTicketDetails() not working

Comment: Can you share the contract as text? In the image there isn't much to evaluate. What are `tickets`, `decryptTicketDetails`, `encryptedDetails`, `decryptionKey`. It could be an error in the contract code, or invalid input parameters.